# Find entries that does not have overlapped dates

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
activity (name, description, dateBegin, dateEnd)
```

I need to find all activities that does not overlap each other (their dates do not collide).

I have the following conditions to find overlapped activities:

```
AND (0
    OR (`activity1`.`dateBegin` <= `activity2`.`dateBegin` AND `activity2`.`dateBegin` < `activity1`.`dateEnd`)
    OR (`activity1`.`dateBegin` < `activity2`.`dateEnd` AND `activity2`.`dateEnd` <= `activity1`.`dateEnd`)

    OR (`activity2`.`dateBegin` <= `activity1`.`dateBegin` AND `activity1`.`dateBegin` < `activity2`.`dateEnd`)
    OR (`activity2`.`dateBegin` < `activity1`.`dateEnd` AND `activity1`.`dateEnd` <= `activity2`.`dateEnd`)
)
```

How do I join the same table twice and calculate the matches without duplicating entries? PS: I have another table called `userActivity` that has a `activityId` and `userId` column to match user columns that I need to `LEFT JOIN` on my query.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A starts before Event B finishes, and ends after Event B starts.

Comment: Yes, thats how it should work

Comment: So you have a lot of redundant code.

Comment: Think just a little bit :D

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)